# Is $\mathbb{A}^n_\mathbb{Q}$ dense in $\mathbb{A}^n_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The title shows it all.
I was able to show this when $n=1$: if $\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $D(f)$ is any principal open set containing $\alpha$, then $D(f)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is nonempty. For, otherwise $f$ must vanish at all points of $\mathbb{Q}$, which forces the polynomial $f$ to be zero, a contradiction.

Then I proceeded to the case $n=2$, where I got stuck.
Suppose we had a polynomial $f\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x,y]$ which vanishes at all rational points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$.
It highly seemsm that $f$ must also vanish in this case, but I cannot prove this.

In general, suppose $V$ is an affine variety over $\mathbb{Q}$.
What condition on $V$ could be posed to make $V$ dense in $V_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$, its base extension to algebraic closure?

Comment: What is $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q}$?

Comment: By $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ I mean the $n$-dimensional affine space over a field $k$.

Comment: Fix $x$ and let $y$ vary. Now you have reduced the 2-dimensional case to the 1-dimensional case.